# Dealing with dead manual links

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I have noticed that there are quite a few links to Blender documentation that have gone down since the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/) URL was changed recently.

Since this change, it seems that some of the older documentation links are not redirecting, and instead give a 404  error like below.

[image]

Some examples:

[How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles/2565#2565)

[What is the difference between a UV Sphere and an Icosphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uv-sphere-and-an-icosphere/73#73)

[Creating a Black Hole in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/creating-a-black-hole-in-blender/23574#23574)

[Make a gold reflective object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/make-a-gold-reflective-object/15684#15684)

[How to change to spherical Axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8731/how-to-change-to-spherical-axis/8734#8734)

While I have read through [this question](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/577/how-to-deal-with-dead-links) and agree with the points made, since these links are the documentation for Blender, it seems to me that it would make more sense to fix them if possible rather than to just remove them.

My main question is, is there a way to search the site specifically for the wiki links/ older documentation links? Then one could update as appropriate if so inclined to ensure that links go to the correct place, and that there is current and correct information. Or would it be better to just update them as they are found?

Comment: For old wiki links, you can view their original content by inserting`?title=` into the URL after `index.php` and before `Doc:2.6`. For example, `https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual` becomes `https://wiki.blender.org/index.php?title=Doc:2.6/Manual`. Can be useful for determining which manual page would be most appropriate.

Comment: That's a useful tip, thanks. I always read through the URL and do my best to judge which page is the correct one based on the content for the ones I have changed. Sometimes, not so easy though to find the right page though.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent incentive. I applaud you on seeing a problem and working towards getting it fixed. I myself still have ~60 posts to fix.
<sub>(I thought sure there was a meta post on this before, but alas I can not find it.)</sub>

Anyway, yes fix them when you come across them. Or if you find yourself with a free hour or two, edit [a whole bunch of them](http://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/642883/blender-wiki-links) (990 as of this writing).  That link answers your main question.

It is rather a bother because you have to go and find the new manual link. [This cross reference](https://gist.github.com/gandalf3/be6e957c00511688073a#file-wiki_manual_redirects-csv) can help when trying to find the new link. There is not direct correlation between the old links and where they put it in the new manual. (Some things are *hard* to find.)

As you alluded to, please do not simply remove a wiki link, change it to the manual's link.